# Web-service Arquitetura e Funcionalidade

Tags: java, jsf, web-service, aplicação-web, jsp

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a Web-service.

É o seguinte tenho uma aplicação em Java EE JSP, onde deve permitir uma conversa com outra aplicação em Android (Exemplo: quando cadastrar uma ata reunião no banco de dados pela aplicação JSP, notificar no APP Android e ter uma opção do usuário ver, o status do relatório da reunião).

Não sei, se é correto: criei um Web-service dentro do projeto JSP, que está pronto (este projeto fáz várias transações como cadastrar, consultar, alterar e excluir dados, etc).

A pergunta é devo ter três aplicativos para comunicação entre ele?

1º criar um Web-service independente, para fazer a integração entre o projeto do JSP com o projeto Android;

2º Projeto JSP independente e Projeto Android independente.

Comment: Por que a tag [tag:jsf] ?

Comment: Neste mesmo projeto JSP, que referi estou usando JSF com Primefaces para um calendário de eventos. Coloquei a tag, porque alguém que trabalha com JSF também poderia ajudar a esclarecer a dúvida. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Josué,

Sim, seu pensamento não está incorreto, na verdade, é até uma arquitetura comum. Vou lhe aconselhar sobre o foco de cada projeto para que a responsabilidade de cada projeto seja bem definido e para que você possa absorver melhor as oportunidades.

Pense em centralizar toda a parte de modelo de negócios e regras na camada model do web service. Em várias situações isso possibilitará uma manutenção mais simples quando quaisquer regra mudar, pois você só precisará atualizar 1 projeto.

O aplicativo Android e o projeto JSP ficarão simples, focando mais no visual. O que é bom principalmente para o aplicativo Android, pois dependendo do tipo processamento que você precise fazer, um servidor é obviamente mais robusto do que um smartphone ou tablet (mas acredito que não seja o caso do seu projeto, apenas um adicional no pensamento).

Você até poderia fazer o web service e o projeto JSP em um único projeto, pois seguindo o MVC, o que seria seu projeto JSP ficaria mais concentrado na View e o Controller poderia ser implementado em formato RestFUL, por exemplo, e assim permitiria que um aplicativo Android faça requisições a ele. É um caso a se avaliar a possibilidade.

Pelo o que pude entender do seu problema, acredito que essas são informações que lhe fariam refletir um pouco mais. Qualquer coisa deixe um comentário!

Comment: Younger, muito obrigado, por me ajudar! Vou seguir a ideia do Web-service e o projeto JSP em um único projeto, porque vai ser melhor. O projeto JSP, que tenho está com bastante transação pronta seguindo o MVC. Cada objeto, já executa seus métodos completos (CRUD). Qualquer novidade em relação a este tópico te passo aqui! Ok?

Comment: Younger, para este contexto a implementação em formato RestFUL é melhor, que SOAP?